# How many packages of cups and plates for a party?

Tags: word-problem

The problem states "cups are sold $6$ to a package and plates are sold $8$ to a package. If you want to have the same number of each item for the party, what is the least number of packages of each you need to buy?"

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: How would you MODEL this problem? MODELING means expressing the information from the problem AND the requirement in mathematical terms. How would you express this word problem as a mathematical problem? Often THIS is the most difficult step, not solving the math problem itself.

Comment: I don't know I cannot find a number that you can multiply 8 and 6 by to get the same amount of each

Comment: You answered mathguy's comment. Now google least common multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a multiple of $6$.  This means that you need $X$ cups. $X$ divided by $6$ equals $4$, so you need $4$ packages of cups.

$X$ is a multiple of $8$.  This means that you need $X$ plates. $X$ divided by $8$ equals $3$, so you need $3$ packages of plates.